# insert current timestamp into mysql with php?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

This is driving me crazy. I've searched it on interent but can't get to a conclusion.

I have a date field in my database. Which I'm retrieving values with date function just fine.

Problem is I did it some time ago, and I don't remember how I inserted those values into that field. it's an integer value (according to what I read, the number of seconds since jan 1st 1970, for example 1338949763. but when I try inserting stuff, like using `INSERT INTO entries (date) VALUES (NOW())` . The `NOW` thing will store a formatted date, like `2012-04-12 23:09:54`. I don't want that. I want to store the integer value. how do I do that?

Answer (score 18):

Use MySQL's `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function to get the current epoch time:

```
INSERT INTO mytable SET tstamp = UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

Comment: Also the `NOW()` is redundant as without an argument `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` will use the current time.

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like `"INSERT INTO entries (date) VALUES ('".time()."')"`

Answer (score 0):

The correct function is:

```
getdate()
```

NOT

```
NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

if u want to insert timestamp i.e. some integer value into mysql field; the field type should be "timestamp" not "datetime" then I hope your integer value will be accepted by the DB

Answer (score 0):

you may try this for insert

```
INSERT into Table_name (colunm_name) VALUES ('".time()."');
```